# Are there idioms specific to one English dialect?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, dialects

Let's get into a little conversation about the differences between American English, British English and regional dialects. Some words are specific to certain dialects (*lass* is Scottish, *the lads* is British, etc.). Some words take different meaning (*theatre* vs. *cinema* to mean “movie theatre”). Pronunciation is obviously different, and spelling can be (*neighbour*/*or*, *gray*/*grey*, etc.).

What I wonder is this: are there some specifically British (or American, or whatever) **idioms**. I don't see why there shouldn't be, but I can't think of a single one right now. So, can you come forward with such idioms with the following constraints:

- the individual words do not markedly belong to one dialect
- it does not refer to a specific cultural element: geographic place, local dish, …

It would be fun to have some from a wide variety of English dialects, to broaden the perspective.

---

*Edit:* to clarify, an idiom in this question has the meaning of “a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words”

Comment: You might need to specify a bit more what you mean: does "5 through 8" (i.e. a construction/prepositional use frequent in US English but not British English) count as an "idiom"? How about "There's nowt as queer as folk"?-- is this an "idiom" or a "proverb" (or both)? And does it "belong" to a dialect? ("nowt" is clearly dialectal at its root, but commonly enough understood to have a TV series named after it...)

Comment: An idiom is “a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words”. So, “5 through 8” is not one. And “there's nowt as queer as folk” is fully understandable by something (like me) who had never heard it. (And I would also rule it out because “nowt” in itself is markedly Northern English.)

Comment: @Neil, what does "5 through 8" mean?  Never heard of that phrase before.

Comment: @F'x -- I think it's worth putting in the question then that that's what you mean by "idiom".

Comment: @Kevin -- the point is that British speakers don't use "through" to mean "to", "up to", "until" with ranges. So to a British speaker, the meaning isn't necessarily 'deducible from the meaning of the individual words' (although a problem with this definition is that the extent to which a meaning is deducible will really depend on the individual speaker).

Comment: @Neil - gotcha.  So if I were to go to England as a teacher and say "Do problems 1 through 20 for homework tonight" I might get some odd stares from my pupils.

Comment: @Neil: I put the defition of “idiom” in the question. It's the dictionary's definition, not mine. I didn't think people had their own private definition :)

Comment: @Kevin -- Yes, it would "sound a bit odd" if they haven't come across this usage. Of course, it's not like there are 1000 possible meanings and UK speakers will work out what is meant (although, for example, UK speakers won't be sensitive to whether "through" is inclusive of the second number in the range).

Comment: @F'x - What precisely is covered by "idiom" isn't particularly fixed in practice. (Remember there's no such thing as "the dictionary"; each different dictionary, of which there are hundreds, offers you the opinion of its particular human editors.)

Comment: "Lass" is not specific to Scotland, it's used in England (mainly the north) as well, and "lad" is its counterpart.

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to be able to identify idioms specific to one english dialect, since either you're not of the region and you are consequently familiar with few such idioms or you *are* of the region and you aren't able to determine whether or not it's used outside of your home town.

I come from the Southern United States, and I'll share a few idioms that may (or may not) be particular to that particular region:

- How about them apples?  (*What you think about that?* or *How about that?"*)
- Well, butter my butt and call me a biscuit! (*I can't believe it!*)
- Well, color me stupid! (*What was I thinking?* or *Agh!  I'm such an idiot!*)
- Bless your heart! (*Oh poor thing!*)
- Dumber than a box of rocks. (I think meaning is evident here o.O)
- Meaner than a sack full of rattlesnakes.  (Nice way to call a child a pest)

These are the ones I've grown up with more frequently, though there are lots more [here](http://socyberty.com/languages/top-75-southern-sayings-and-southern-dictionary/) if you're interested.

Comment: The real Southern woman can actually use "Bless your heart!" to call you a dumb@$$ while you think she is being kind to you.

Comment: Sadly, true.  :)

Answer (score 8):

I grew up in Glasgow, Scotland. One that always amused me was the phrase "your bum is hanging out the window", pronounced "Yer bum's hingin' oot the windae", which means roughly "you don't know what you are talking about", or "you are talking nonsense." Occasionally, and sarcastically you might hear a Glaswegian say, in an affected way, "Your posterior has been defenestrated", Which means, basically the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

An excellent example of this can be found in Cockney rhyming slang. These are formed by joining two words, such that the intended meaning is a word that rhymes with the second one in the expression, e.g.:

> - trouble and strife (wife)
> - frog and toad (road)
> - apple and pears (stairs)

There is no equivalent of it, to my knowledge, in US English.

Comment: The critical point is that you only say the first one - so unless you know the rhyme it makes no sense. "Lets have a butchers" = have a look (butcher's hook = look)

Comment: Is this like 'Barney' meaning 'trouble' from Ocean's Eleven?

Comment: @Kevin - yes, a modern addition: Barney Rubble = Trouble.

Comment: Another modern one: "I don't have a Scooby".  (Scooby Doo: clue)

Answer (score 4):

I was part of a group trip to New Zealand in November and saw this sign:
[image]

Our tour guide had to explain. Here's from [this webpage](http://www.chemistry.co.nz/kiwi.htm#rack_off):

> rattle your dags: hurry up; get a move on. And from Jeff Law...The expression 'Rattle your dags' reputedly refers to a somewhat mucky sheep 'rattling it's [sic] dags (dried excretia hanging from the wool)' when running!

Comment: But isn't the word *dags* specific to this dialect region?

Comment: I second Kosmonaut: *dag* is noted as “Austral./NZ informal” in the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.

Comment: 'dags' is common wherever you need to refer to dried-on sheep shit - it's only in Australia that it's universally a part of the culture

Comment: @Kosmonaut: oops, I missed that part of the OPs Q somehow.

Answer (score 2):

In a couple of weeks, several thousand idiots and masochists are going to walk 40 miles from Keswick to Barrow (Lake District, UK). Those who are too stupid to give up, and actually complete the walk, are conferred the title '[Master of the Fellowship of the Ancient Order of the Barking Dogs](http://www.keswick2barrow.co.uk/recognition.asp)'.

I'm not sure what the origins of the phrase are, and I know that the terms is used in some other pockets of the country/world, but in general, few outside the area will know that if your `dogs are barking` you actually have sore feet.

Comment: 'my dogs are barking' is not an uncommon phrase in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'll go the the foot of our stairs *- I wish to express a degree of surprise.* (Yorkshire)

I don't know if it's bored or punched *I don't know whether I'm coming or going.  I've heard this in Yorkshire and Lancashire.  I think there are more vulgar versions of this which specify what is either bored or punched.*

Answer (score 1):

There are number of Australian idioms, too. Many of the more well-known ones are more common in rural areas or amongst older generations, but there are newer ones, too.

*chuck a ewe-y* means to do a U-turn, usually in a car (and despite my spelling, nothing to do with sheep)

*have a smoko* means break for (usually) morning tea

I'm sure I'll think of more after I post this...

Comment: Americans *hang a ewe-y*, although I don't think we spell it that way.

Comment: I spelt it that way so people would know how we say it. :-) I don't know how Aussies would write that down, TBH!

Comment: well, if you live up to your nickname, you'll be interested to know that Google statistically favors *U-ie*.

Answer (score 0):

'To get off after Barking' - to get off the train after the Barking station (Barking mad).

Useage: That geezer gets off two stops after Barking.

Meaning: That man is Barking Mad.

Answer (score 0):

One phrase I picked up from my friends across The Pond:

"Throw a Wobbly" - In America, we would say "Pitch a fit" or "Have a hissy fit."

Uniquely American:

"[Person] is about as sharp as a sack of wet mice." Which is to say, "not very bright." 
"Going postal" - To go violently insane. Refers to a spate of incidents involving US postal workers in the 1980s. 
"Wall Street" - Matters of high finance. Refers to a street in the Financial District in New York City.
"Ten-four" or "10-4" mean "Affirmative" or "OK". It's a brevity code commonly used in radio transmissions. [APCO Definitions from 1940](http://www.apcohistory.org/pdf/1940-01-jan_pages1-12.pdf)